# Get XML Attributes using PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to get the URL of the image in . The XML document tree is as follow:

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>
        <![CDATA[ The Star Online Business Highlights ]]>
    </title>
    <link>/TheStar/Website</link>
    <description>...</description>
    <image>...</image>
    <language>en</language>
    <item>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">{F88B27DD-24FB-4807-941F-070D772B7586}</guid>
        <link>
            http://www.thestar.com.my/business/business-news/2017/10/24/top-glove-says-not-buying-adventa-nor-supermax/
        </link>
        <title>
            <![CDATA[ Top Glove says not buying Adventa nor Supermax ]]>
        </title>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[KUALA LUMPUR: Top Glove, which has allocated about RM1bil to expand via mergers, has denied news reports the target companies are Adventa Bhd and Supermax Corporation Bhd.]]>
        </description>
        <pubDate>Tue, 24 Oct 2017 13:17:18 +08:00</pubDate>
        <enclosure url="http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/online/2017/08/22/03/58/hartalega-glove3.ashx?crop=1&w=0&h=0&" length="" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <media:content url="http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/online/2017/08/22/03/58/hartalega-glove3.ashx?crop=1&w=0&h=0&" type="image/jpeg">
            <media:description>
                <![CDATA[ ]]>
            </media:description>
        </media:content>
        <section>
            <![CDATA[ Business ]]>
        </section>
    </item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
</channel>
```

As there is multiple item and I want to make it a loop, I tried:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $news) { 
    $media = $news->media->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    echo ($media->content);
}
```

and also

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $news) { 
    $media = $news->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    echo ($media->content);
}
```

but both are seems failed. What is the right method?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925300/parsing-media-rss-using-xmlreader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$media` variable is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).
What you could do is loop your `$media` variable in a foreach and then get your `url` from the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

For example (using [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) with [additional Libxml parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) to load your example xml:

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
//Your example xml here
SOURCE;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR|LIBXML_ERR_NONE|LIBXML_ERR_FATAL);

foreach($xml->channel->item as $news) {
    $media = $news->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    foreach($media as $child) {
        echo $child->attributes()->url;
    }
}
```

Will result in:

`http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/online/2017/08/22/03/58/hartalega-glove3.ashx?crop=1=0=0`

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, LIBXML_NOERROR|LIBXML_ERR_NONE|LIBXML_ERR_FATAL);
foreach ($xml->xpath("//media:content") as $node)
{
    var_dump ((string) $node["url"]);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.